# Add AUTOTEXT to MS Word Document with Power Shell

Tags: powershell, scripting, ms-word

I am working on a project where I need to add AUTOTEXT entries like the Page 1 of X listings to the header and footer of a Power Shell generated MS Word document.  I have tried extracting ideas from the [following C# examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178795%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y570), but I cannot seem to figure out how to make it work.  I was curious if someone could share some code to help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point. This function add page number to the footer of document passed as parameter ( used on word 2010):

```
function Add-PageFooter ([string]$Document) {

add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" 

set-variable -name wdAlignPageNumberCenter -value 1 -option constant

$fc1 =  "Page"

$word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True
#$Word.Visible = $False

$fc2 = [ref] "" -as [Type]

$OpenDoc = $Word.Documents.Open($Document)
$c = $OpenDoc.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(1).PageNumbers.Add($wdAlignPageNumberCenter)
$range1 = $openDoc.Sections.Item(1).Footers.Item(1).range
$field1 = $OpenDoc.Fields.Add($range1, -1, $fc2)
$field1.Code.Text = $fc1
$field1.Update

#$OpenDoc.Close() 
}
```

Another way is to create a Word `Macro` and execute from powershell:

```
$wd = new-object -comobject word.application # create a com object interface (word application)

$wd.documents.open("C:\word\test.doc") # open doc

$wd.run("Macro01") # exec macro named macro01 that add custom footer and/or header

$wd.quit() # exit application
```

The `macro` must be saved on `normal.dot` (`normal.dotm` for 2010 and above) to have it in all open documents.

In this way you can customize what you want in a word document and not just header/footer  recording in a macro your actions in the docs.